# Cannot access Windows via grub after new dual-boot Ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I previously installed Ubuntu on a computer that had Windows XP on it and got it successfully to run alongside it. (access both OS systems)

Now I installed Ubuntu again on my MSI notebook with Windows 8.1, and I cannot access the GRUB without hitting escape on startup, and even then, I can no longer open windows.

Before all of this, I created a recovery point, file history and saved a back up on a external hard drive incase I did anything wrong.

Now how can I revert my computer back to it's state before installation.

Comment: Include the output of `sudo os-prober` and the grub file resulting of `sudo grub-mkconfig > grub`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no magic Undo button, but my guess to do this effectively would be to completely remove Ubuntu by deleting the Ubuntu partitions, then seeing if you can boot Windows 8.1. Then use Disk Management to make the Windows 8.1 partition big again. I have heard that problems are very common when trying to dual-boot with Windows 8 and 8.1, you might want to look around on the Ubuntu Wiki for help on doing the install again. Disabling Hibernation and Fast Boot in Windows 8.1 might be necessary before attempting to install Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the submission by @FuzzyToothpaste, see my answer to a similar question:

["This computer currently has no detected operating systems."- Ubuntu 14.04 install Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475352/this-computer-currently-has-no-detected-operating-systems-ubuntu-14-04-insta/475387#475387)

which outlines the steps involved to dual-booting with Windows 8.1, with a link to detailed instructions.

**Clarification**: did you erase the Windows partition during install, or is it simply inaccessible?

If it was removed,as you have a saved back-up image, this link may also prove useful:
http://www.winhelp.us/system-image-backup-in-windows-8-1.html

It discusses the steps involved with restoring Windows 8.1 from a back-up image using the *Recovery Environment*.

***Amended***
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/restore-computer-from-system-image-backup#1TC=windows-7
This link, in response to OP comment, is a breakdown of the steps involved to boot Windows 8.1 using your System Backup Image. Three options are offered:
1) restore using the Recovery Control Panel(this is the recommended option)
2) restore using pre-installed recovery options
3) restore using Windows installation disc or system repair disc

*Note:Available options will differ based on your hardware. These are general instructions, refer to your hardware manual for specifics on terminology of these options, and HotKey commands to access BIOS, if necessary.*

**Related**: see this link:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/aptio-setup-utility-asus-n56vj-need-help-windows-8/b115c448-953b-4f9e-8187-19256f0e0977

The above lists the Setup Utility directions specific to your hardware(or as close as I could find) for restoring Windows from Installation Media. The below listed method(from link) is the closest to your intended use.

***Method 1:***

Boot to Recovery Environment with the installation media:

Please follow the steps given below. Insert the Windows 8 installation DVD in the DVD ROM and restart your computer.

a) After you boot your computer using Windows DVD or System Repair Disc, a black screen appears with gray text "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD". Press any key.

b) Select the correct time and Keyboard type.

c) Click Repair your computer in the lower left corner.

d) Select Troubleshoot from Choose an option screen.

e) Click Advanced options in Troubleshoot screen.

f) Click Automatic Repair from Advanced Options screen.

g) Next, choose the operating system.

h) Windows 8 will then look for problems on hard drive(s) and verify that all required files are intact.

***Related Notes:***
Should any of the above resolve the issue, in the future, see

[this handy guide for dual-booting WIndows 8 and Ubuntu in 10 easy steps](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Comment: I didn't choose that option, but if know realize that I screwed up with the partitions when I clicked "something else"

Comment: That link shows how to create one, but do you possibly know how to boot the hard drive with the system recovery image?

Comment: @user287474, please see my amended answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Although, on my laptop, there's no option to repair my computer..

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwBHUmUdPMO-THN1U29SaWE2LTA/edit?usp=docslist_api this is what's happening

Comment: I'm not enormously familiar with Aptio, I run an HP, but what shows in the BOOT section?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwBHUmUdPMO-empROWFROGxJeUE/edit?usp=docslist_api here @SonOfEntropy

Comment: @user287474, see my edited answer, at bottom of post. If the listed option does not suit your needs, explore the rest of the page. Should be able to find something to help.

Comment: I would, if I had a cd or DVD recovery disk. I'm starting to think that my system image on my hard drive is useless..

Comment: Did you make a separate partition on the drive for backup? if so, does it show as a bootable drive in Setup Utility?

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted it after fuzzytoothpaste's suggestion. At this point I'm asking if some of my friends can make and give me a recovery disk. That should work, right?

Comment: *should*, yes. See my amended answer(bottom) for future guides. Also, in the future, please respond to any requests for clarification through comments by adjusting your question to show requested info, so other users can easily see it as well.