# System image recovery

Tags: boot, hard-drive, software-installation

I need to restore my computer from Ubuntu to the system image backup I created on my hard drive before I started installation. Please help

I screwed with the partitions before hand, and this back up is my only home. Please help, I'm panicking.

Answer (score 0):

First off, just relax. See my answer to a similar question in the forum:
[Cannot access Windows via grub after new dual-boot Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475403/help-ubuntu-installation/475409#475409)

The lower section, marked ***Amended***, contains a link to a series of options for booting Windows from a series of different sources, with a System Backup Image using Recovery Control Panel being the recommended option, although you may need to use pre-installed recovery options, depending on the state of your Windows installation.