# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10, legacy BIOS non-UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, uefi, bios

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 (Legacy BIOS), but whenever I try and install, I get this:

[image: dual boot]

Is there a solution from here? Can I just press the option not to force UEFI, and carry on with installation?

I followed [this guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside_8.html) exactly, but the `"Force UEFI installation?"` occurs at the `"Preparing to install Ubuntu"` stage.

Comment: If the machine is UEFI capable why on Earth have you installed Windows in Legacy? Now, if you need a proper dual boot you need to boot the Ubuntu installer in the same way, i.e., not UEFI. How it boots is how it installs.

Comment: I upgraded from an old version of Windows, which I guess was installed in Legacy. I tried to boot it in non UEFI, but that takes me straight back to the Windows loading screen. Any ideas how to boot it in the same way?

Comment: Windows should boot the same exact way if you disable UEFI (= CSM or Legacy only). That way the USB should boot in legacy. Otherwise there will be two entry for the some drive; choose the one without UEFI. If it doesn't boot that way it means it was probably done with Rufus or similar tool that forces one mode or another. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows (notice the "partition scheme"; you need the option pictured - MBR - for booting in non-UEFI systems).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now another stage further in dual booting. I believe the wrong selection was made before when creating the USB stick. I used Rufus and changed the partition scheme to MBR and it has now worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when attempting to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine running Windows 10 with legacy BIOS. This process might help:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1069984/616171