# Getting "This computer currently has no detected operating systems." while installing Ubuntu 23.10 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, secure-boot, 23.10

After carefully reviewing answers to these similar questions:

1. ["This computer currently has no detected operating systems."-
   Ubuntu 14.04 install Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475352/this-computer-currently-has-no-detected-operating-systems-ubuntu-14-04-insta)
2. ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something
   Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)
3. [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed
   Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

I am facing this message while trying to install Ubuntu 23.10 alongside Windows 10 which is already installed: "This computer currently has no detected operating systems. what would you like to do?"

Previously I had Ubuntu 22.04 and there was no such problem when installing the prior versions of Ubuntu. System Specs and Configurations:

- Laptop: Lenovo z50-70
- Intel Virtual Technology: Disabled
- Secure boot: Disabled
- Secure boot status: Disabled
- Boot mode: UEFI
- Fast Boot: Disabled

The status of Windows partitions and those for Ubuntu are healthy.

[image]

I made the USB bootable using the Rufus and the Ubuntu iso file was downloaded from the Ubuntu website.

**Update**

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 23.10 (Legacy Desktop Installer)
Rufus 4.3.2090, configs:

- Partition Scheme: MBR
- Target system: BIOS or UEFI
- File system: large FAT32 (Default)
- Cluster size: 32 Kilobytes (Default)

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 23.10, but not which 23.10 product. The Server ISO uses `subiquity`, where as if you were installing a Desktop ISO there are two installers selected by the ISO you download and install. You didn't specify which product (Server/Desktop) you are using, and if Desktop which installer you tried (*or if you tried both*).  If 23.10 *flavor* different installers are used too (*with a choice for Budgie like Ubuntu Desktop*).  Some reformat options of ISO write can cause *bootloader* to fail to install, but you didn't specify if `rufus` was updated & what options were used

Comment: @guiverc: I downloaded ubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso.

Comment: Your last comment by ISO file-name is the 23.10 of the Desktop ISO using the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, where as the `ubiquity` or *legacy* installed is found in ISO named `https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/23.10/release/ubuntu-23.10-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso`  (note: legacy in name!)  Your last comment contradicts edits to question which imply *legacy*.  After install (*if system boots*) the results will be identical, but both install differently.